# How does javascript allocate memory?

Tags: javascript, c, memory

I have a C background and I have just started to learn about Javascript. In C, when I create a variable and initialize it, (Ex. `int foo`), space is reserved in the stack for my variable. Different amounts of space are reserved for different types (Ex. `int, bool, unsigned int, double`). In Javascript there is only one type (`var`) I can instantiate it as a string literal(Ex. `var person="John Doe";`) or a number (Ex. `var x=5;`). How can Javascript store these values without knowing how much space will need to be allocated for the variable?

Comment: Javascript doesn't allocate memory at all, a Javascript implementation does. And it's quite possible that different implementations use different methods.

Comment: The type is deduced from the context and the type determines the memory needed for the variable.

Comment: See this article [A tour of V8: object representation](http://www.jayconrod.com/posts/52/a-tour-of-v8-object-representation) for an overview of how V8 Javascript engine represents Javascript objects.

Answer (score 1):

Javascript is dynamically typed and uses automatic memory allocation and reclamation. From an implementation perspective, you can imagine that every variable is some kind of set of data pointers and function pointers; more accurately like a polymorphic base class pointer in C++. The memory for the objects is managed for you by the runtime environment, though, and does not need manual intervention. Some kind of garbage collection is a likely implementation.